# Is 64 bit right for my AMD Athlon XP?

Tags: 11.10, 64-bit

I have AMD Athlon XP 1.2 Ghz, 1 GB DDR RAM.
I don't know if I can install all drivers.

Answer (score 1):

The Athlon XP CPU does not have support for 64-bit instruction thus you cannot use the Ubuntu 64-bit installation.

The Athlon XP is a K7 architecture CPU with support for 32-bit instructions only.

Answer (score 0):

The 32bit architecture will do just fine for your PC setup.

Drivers are less of an issue, you would need some rather exotic hardware to not to be supported by either architecture.

As example: my workstation is an i7 2.3Ghz CPU with 8GiB RAM, but got by accident an 32bit installation of Ubuntu 11.10. And it runs fairly well - with the 8GiB used at max.

Comment: And can you use all your 8 GiB RAM in a 32-bit system?

Comment: Yes, I do it quiet well, running several VMs in the background, each 1024 - 2048 MiB. And still doing much more - all that on the 32bit architecture.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann [PAE Kernels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension) allow that.

Comment: @Bruno (and marc): Thanks, learning something new every day.